# Mouse down on sub-widget, but which one?

Tags: qt

Think of a window designed with Qt Designer. Lots of sub-widgets. There is a QWidget derived class for this window which implements the virtual mouse methods of QWidget (mousePressEvent, mouseReleaseEvent, mouseMoveEvent)

Some of the sub-widgets are clean of controls, and are defined in the stylesheet as "background: transparent"

My question:

When such a transparent sub-widget is clicked, i do get the MousePressEvent called in my QWidget derived class. That's all fine. I do however would like to know WHICH sub-widget was just clicked. I'd like to avoid geometry comparisons to map the click location to the dimensions of my sub-widgets.

Is there a way to get this information from the mouseEvent object? I can't seem to see anything there related to the **originator** of the mouse event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should write class (inherited from QObject) with reimplemented `bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);` function.
2. You should install instance of this class as event filter in all needed subwidgets: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter.

In reimplemented `bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);` function you can identify which subwidgets get MouseEvent first.

Answer (score 0):

Call [QWidget::childAt (event -> pos())](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#childAt).